# Android Espresso UI tests for custom views

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

I have created my own custom view which I use in one of my layouts. The class draws a canvas with the following parameters (see below). Is it possible to test my custom view using Android's Espresso UI tests?

The custom view class:

```
public class DialBrightness extends View {
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH_DP = 1;
    private static final int DEFAULT_NUM_RAYS = 8;
    private int mMax;
    private int mMin;
    private int mValue;
    private Paint mInactivePaint;
    private Paint mActivePaint;
    private int mRayGap = 4;
    private boolean showBorder = false;
```

The xml layout:

```
<com.myapp.ui.view.DialBrightness
            android:id="@+id/dial_brightness"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:brightness_active_color="@color/accent"
            app:brightness_inactive_color="@color/xlight_gray"
            app:brightness_stroke_width_active="@dimen/aware_active_stroke"
            app:brightness_stroke_width_inactive="@dimen/aware_active_stroke"
            app:brightness_min="0"
            app:brightness_max="4"
            app:brightness_default="2"
            app:brightness_border="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Did you find a way to test this?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to test about it? Yes there are some things that you can test using Espresso... For example, if you just wanted to check if it's present, you'd do:

```
onView(withId(R.id.dial_brightness)).check(matches(isDisplayed());
```

Check out the cheat sheet, that will give you an idea of the sorts of things that you can test using Espresso. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/cheat-sheet.html

Comment: I want to test if the image that I've drawn is the same as the expected drawn image.